# usleep reaches max limit very quickly, how to prolong

Tags: php

I put my code on sleep when no data returned by server. But it gives me this error after a while being idle.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in
```

I know, changing the max limit in php.ini would help. But i don't want to do this, because I don't own the server...so I can't be changing each clients server limit.

how can I set the max limit to infinity here or probably how to reconnect if reached max?

```
while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif)
    {

      usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU
      clearstatcache();
      $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
    }
```

Comment: Your while is loop infinite  and not exit from loop any time,check your condition

Comment: @ashkufaraz, my while loop does exit on condition..

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); write this in your top of script

Comment: @DineshBhojvani, I've tried set_time_limit(0); and it's working too..but which is better? will your suggestion would atke effect when php run in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set it to zero. Zero means the script can run forever. Add the following at the start of your script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

- `set_time_limit()` does not return anything so you can't use it to detect whether it succeeded. Additionally, it'll throw a warning:

  > Warning: set_time_limit(): Cannot set time limit in safe mode
- `ini_set()` returns `FALSE` on failure and does not trigger warnings.

Comment: will this take effect in safe mode too?

Comment: I've tried set_time_limit(0); and it seems to be working too.. which is better?

Comment: set_time_limit(): Cannot set time limit in safe mode